# Communication between cordova app and native app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am building a cordova app which will communicate with a device using BLE in background using https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

**Here are the challenges I am facing :**

1. I want this app to be kind of a service to be used by another native app i.e communication between cordova and native app. I assume both apps need to be opened in background or one of them in foreground for this to work. Is it possible? How?
2. This cordova app will be a separate apk. But is it possible that it can be a part of native app so that user only have to install the native app without installing the cordova app separately?
3. Such app which continuously scans for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) peripherals is eventually be cleared by mobile OS to conserve battery. Is there any way to have it opened in background all the time. I know in android you can disable battery optimizations for a particular app. But what about IOS?
4. Is it maintainable across different platforms(both IOS and android)? Or native implementation will be a better choice?

Comment: I really don't think cordova is what you want to use for what you want to do. Cordova is mainly usefull when you want to build an app with UI using html, but not at all to build a service.

Comment: @QuickFix I know it is an unconventional way. But, are there any technical limitations in implementing such service in cordova?